# How to use a script within another script connecting to MySql

Tags: mysql

I looked through the suggested other posts though I didn't see what I was looking for. This may seem basic to most of you here, so please forgive my simplicity, but I'm stuck.
So below is what I have and it's working. (not everything is showing of the page). What I want to do is call the "payment_status" from a different database completely.
What my question is, is how can I use this, and then have another script within this just to pull that column from a different database. I'm using PHP.

What I have

```
    <?php
    $servername = " ";
    $username = " ";
    $password = " ";
    $dbname = " ";
    
    
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT id, name, email, payment_status, FROM paymenttable";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
    echo "<div id='firstentry" . $row["id"]. "'><font color='yellow'>Name:</font> <span class='name'>" . $row["name"]. "</span> <br>";   // This uses the first database listed
    
    echo "<font color='yellow'>Payment Status:</font>  <span class='payment_status'>" . $row["payment_status"]. "</span>";  // This is what needs called from a different database than the rest of the page

    echo "<div id='next entry" . $row["id"]. "'><font color='yellow'>Email:</font> <span class='email'>" . $row["email"]. "</span> <br>";  // This uses the first database listed
```

Comment: I’m not sure where you’re setting $row, maybe I missed it? Also, does the other database exist on the same server as the initial DB? You can simply do two connections. One to DB A and the other to DB B, two separate connection variables.

Comment: Yes the $row isn't showing on here. Most of the page I left out because it would just be clutter. The only part I'm struggling with is how to make it so that one line reads from a different database. Both databases are on the same server :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification around it being on the same server, that’s important. I’ve posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can connect to two different databases on the same server by **not** specifying the database in the connection string:

```
$dbname1 = " ";
$dbname2 = " ";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Second, use [mysqli_select_db](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) to change your default database.

Select your **first** database, write your **first** query, then select your **second** database, and write your **second** query. You can write it in ether object oriented style, or procedural style:

**Object oriented style:**

```
$conn -> select_db($dbname1);
//write your first query again database 1 here

$conn -> select_db($dbname2);
//write your second query again database 2 here
```

**Procedural style:**

```
mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname1);
//write your first query again database 1 here

mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname2);
//write your second query again database 2 here
```

Next, output your results using `echo` here, be sure to differentiate your results between the two queries using `$row1` and `$row2` for example.

Finally, close your connection:

```
mysqli_close($conn);
```